# Developers or software experts who use or who developed asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, open-source, blogs

As I am new to asp.net mvc I would like to get the list of developers or software experts who use or developed asp.net mvc ... It would be very useful for budding developers like me to know about their articles and ideas towards devlopement...

I know a few

- [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/Scottgu/)
- [Stephen Walther](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/)

I want some more authors and their blogs because it would be very helpful to see what they faced during their developement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important one would probably be [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/). Hes a Senior Program Manager at MS working on ASP.NET MVC

Comment: @Darko I ve seen his site but i dont know his name...

Comment: I'd look for Eilon as he's the current dev owner of it.

Comment: Eilon Lipton's blog is :http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/default.aspx hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

[Steve Sanderson](http://blog.codeville.net/). He wrote the [xVal](http://www.codeplex.com/xval) project as well as what I consider the definitive ASP.NET MVC book [Pro ASP.NET MVC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210079)

Comment: +1 for Steve Sanderson's book. The only book I needed to read to learn ASP.NET MVC. Serves as a great reference guide also.

Answer (score 2):

One of them I Know is [Brad Wilson](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/team/view)
Who is Senior Programmer in MVC team. also because aspnetmvc is open source you can find Developres in Codeplex and you may want take a look to this link :http://aspnet.codeplex.com/team/view.

Comment: Mike Brind is a MVP and has a great blog in ASP.NET MVC & .NET:
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/

Answer (score 2):

Scott Hanselman wrote [Professional ASP.Net MVC 1.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470384611) with [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/), [Rob Conery](http://blog.wekeroad.com/) and [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/Scottgu/). He blogs at [hanselman.com](http://www.hanselman.com) and podcasts at [hanselminutes.com](http://www.hanselminutes.com)